# undefined method for a .match? regex

Tags: ruby

I can't figure out why I keep receiving an error. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I also used `include?` to find `"CA"`, but both are reporting an unidentified method.

```
def welcome (address)
  If address.include? "CA"
     print "Welcome to California"
  else
     print "You should move to California"
end

welcome(717 California St, CA, 94111)
```

Comment: @lucke84 Your edit is unacceptable. You can touch the title and the text, but syntactic mistake in the code is often the crucial part of the OP's problem, and should not be changed. Furthermore, even if you were to fix the syntax, it does not make sense to partially fix the syntax and leave some other syntactic mistake. Regarding your edit on the text, **unidentified method** is not particularly something verbatim from the console, and there is no reason to put it in backticks.

Comment: @sawa thanks for the explanation. I paid attention not to change anything which was part of the problem itself, my intention was actually to made the problem clearer, eliminating all and only the noise. For what concerns the *unidentified method*, I thought it was a typo for *undefined*, as the title states, therefore the backticks.

Answer (score 1):

you should change the call to a string:

```
welcome(717 California St, CA, 94111)
```

to  7 California St', 'CA', 94111)f

```
welcome("717 California St, CA, 94111")
```

The first call is read as three separate arguments: `717 California St`, `CA`, and 94111

since the first two are not defined, you'll get an error from them.  The last argument is an integer, but it's still meaningless to the `welcome` method.

the second instance `welcome("717 California St, CA, 94111")` passes the address as one argument to the `welcome` method.  Since it is a string in this case, your `welcome` method can now search it.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I am still understanding how this works. After looking at your response it seemed obvious, thanks again.